# Cucumber test failed : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/plugin/SummaryPrinter

Tags: selenium-webdriver, installation, cucumber, bdd

I was trying to execute basic test from Cucumber feature file but found the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/plugin/SummaryPrinter
```

Feature File:

---

```
Feature: Login Action

Scenario: Successful Login with Valid Credentials
    Given User is on Home Page
    When User Navigate to LogIn Page
    And User enters UserName and Password
    Then Message displayed Login Successfully

Scenario: Successful LogOut
    When User LogOut from the Application
    Then Message displayed LogOut Successfully
```

---

Test Runner File:

---

```
package test;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "Feature"
        ,glue={"stepdefinition"}
        )

public class TestRunner {

}
```

---

I am using eclipse and have installed cucumber plugin through eclipse marketplace.
Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
package cucumberOptions;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

//@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/java/features",
        glue = "stepDefinations")
public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

}
```

Just keep in mind that features, stepDefinations, are folders at the same level, also my testRunner class is inside a folder called 'cucumberOptions' which is at the same level than the other 2 folders, in my case they are inside test folder, since this is a maven like project

Answer (score 0):

It looks that missing dependency of one of the jar. It's really bean hectic and cumbersome with new versions of cucumber as there are always coming with  breaking changes. I also seen same error while upgrading from cucumber `5.1.3` to `5.7.0`. After spending sometime i resolved it  by adding below additional dependency in pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```